# How to Get Image Path From SurfaceView android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

How to get the Image path from `SurfaceView` till now i tried this code

```
public class CameraSwitch extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private Cursor mImageCursor;
    private ImageThumbnailAdapter mAdapter;
    private TwoWayGridView mImageGrid;
    Camera camera;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    boolean previewing = false;
    LayoutInflater controlInflater = null;

    int camId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
    int numberOfCamera;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.cameraswitch);

        surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
        View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);


        Button switchCam = (Button)findViewById(R.id.flip);
    //    Button toggleFlash = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toggleflash);

        LayoutParams layoutParamsControl = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);


        switchCam.setOnClickListener(this);

    initGrid();


        Button picbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        picbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                camera.takePicture(null,null, new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()));
            }
        });
     }

    private void initGrid() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("Bottom Grid View", "Grid view Bottom");

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void openFrontFacingCamera() {
        numberOfCamera = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
          if(camId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK){
          camId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BACK TO FRONT" ,1000).show();
                try {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "try block BACK TO FRONT" ,1000).show();
                         camera.release();
                    camera = Camera.open(camId);
                    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                    //camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);


                    /* Comment this set previewDisplay*/
                   // camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                    camera.startPreview();
                    previewing = true;
                    } 
                catch (RuntimeException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                catch (Exception e) {}
        }
        else if(camId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT){
            camId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FRONT TO BACK" ,1000).show();
                    try {
                        camera.release();
                        camera = Camera.open(camId);
                        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                        camera.startPreview();

                    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View click) {
        if(click.getId() == R.id.flip){
            openFrontFacingCamera();

        }else if(click.getId() == R.id.flip){
            openFrontFacingCamera();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        if(previewing)
        {
            camera.stopPreview();
            previewing = false;
        }
        if (camera != null){

            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                camera.startPreview();
                previewing = true;
            } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        camera = Camera.open(camId);

        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        previewing = false;
    }
}
```

Picture Handler Class

```
 import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PhotoHandler implements PictureCallback {

  private final Context context;

  public PhotoHandler(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }

  @Override
  public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

    File pictureFileDir = getDir();

    if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) {

   //   Log.d(MakePhotoActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "Can't create directory to save image.");
      Toast.makeText(context, "Can't create directory to save image.",
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      return;

    }

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
    String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    String photoFile = "Picture_" + date + ".jpg";

    String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + photoFile;

    Log.e("path", filename.toString());

    File pictureFile = new File(filename);

    try {
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
      fos.write(data);
      fos.close();
      Toast.makeText(context, "New Image saved:" + photoFile,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception error) {
    //  Log.d(MakePhotoActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "File" + filename + "not saved: "
      //    + error.getMessage());
      Toast.makeText(context, "Image could not be saved.",
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }

  private File getDir() {
    File sdDir = Environment
      .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    return new File(sdDir, "Demo App");
  }
}
```

till now i tried this 
Thanks

Comment: you have one method getDir right. make it public.

Comment: after that log the getDir using instance of PhotoHandler.

Answer (score 0):

In the takePicture() method one parameter is picture callback. You have to implement that callback and its method on picture taken. It will give you the image data in bytes. You can save the image from there and after that you can do whatever you want to do with that data. This link might help you
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PictureCallback.html

Comment: hi Bhavin Parmar i have already did this by PhotoHandler class and now i want to get capture Image path from that folder to CameraSwitch Class.

Comment: You can make File pictureFileDir a global member or  store the path of the image while capturing in the database.